Digital Ocean App Platform Vite Not Found
I have a vuejs frontend building on digital ocean app platform as a static site. For a couple of months now, I have been building using the build command: vite build  - and everything has been building fine. Vite has always been a dev dependency in my project and it has always built successfully. Today I'm getting this error:
DO app platform build error (fails immediately):
Running custom build command: npm run build
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │ > project@1.0.0 build
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │ > vite build
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │ sh: 1: vite: not found
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │ building: exit status 127
[2024-05-07 13:21:23] │ ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1 

package.json:
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^7.4.47",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "vite": "^5.2.11"
  }
}

I've tried updating dependencies and deleted package-lock.json (to have it rebuilt) and pushed a new update but it still fails. Is there any simple reason why this would all of a sudden not build correctly?

What is your Node version? Does it still build locally on your machine? Maybe ask the question on their forums directly. You can also always try to host it on Netlify for debugging purposes, just to be sure that this is a Digitalocean problem and not your code.

The problem was the node_modules were being cached from earlier versions. The solution was to go to the main app area under Actions and Force Rebuild & Deploy and checking the Clear the Cache checkbox on the next screen. Everything is working great now.

Yeah this happens with other platforms sometimes too.
